# Is it considered acceptable to have no comments in good Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, documentation, comments

I reviewed some professional code written in Ruby and found no comments. The code was reasonably clear to read but not self-documenting. Should I expect professionally written Ruby code to have comments? Or, is there some Ruby doctrine that comments are not considered essential?

Comment: Relevant: http://rubyrogues.com/what-makes-beautiful-code/

Comment: @Close voter: How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 5):

This issue isn't unique to Ruby.

Code comments should be kept to an absolute minimum, because they are usually not updated when the code changes, and become more misleading than helpful.

As you have already suggested, the best code is self-documenting and requires no comments.

Edit: to clarify, if you cannot reduce the code to remove the complexity, you *must* provide comments. This is rare in my experience, and usually only applies when external components don't behave as you might expect.

Comment: Comments should only be used with code that gives different results then expected (e.g. when dealing with floating point precision errors).

Comment: Comments should be kept up-to-date with code changes, that's not a big effort and certainly not big enough to pose an excuse for not writing comments. And OP certainly _didn't_ suggest that the best code is self-documenting.

Comment: self-documenting code is only viable for easy tasks. any complex code *needs* some comments.

Comment: I have clarified my answer.  yi_H - complex code is usually bad code.  On the other hand, complex systems are fine by me, and how I earn a living ;)

Answer (score 5):

Matz, the creator of Ruby, states his philosophy here and there: "The source code is the documentation. It even states all the bugs correctly." And he probably means that for comments as well. I think many people who don't comment in Ruby source code are following his words. Whether for you to follow him is up to you.

I have also read some Ruby introductory websites saying that, whenever you feel the necessity to comment, that is an indication that you should split that routine as in individual method, and name it as you were to comment that part.

Comment: Thanks for the quote! I still don't buy his argument (in my view code can be a great documentation for the what/how but not for the why/rationale) but you've answered my question in the sense that this is an accepted practice in the Ruby world.

Comment: Well stated! I completely agree with your perspective on this issue @sawa

Comment: Agreed. Use comments when the *intent* is not clear. Good code needs fewer comments.